# Cell value format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to change how a cell appears in Excel, but I'm not sure how to do it. Let's say that we have a worksheet WSA with some data:

[image]

We also have some worksheet WSB in which I want to copy data from WSA:

[image]

However, in the WSB:A1 cell I don't want to see a number 2, but the data from WSA row 2 instead, something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadn't used this myself, but this is something where the INDEX function would come in handy (https://exceljet.net/index-and-match)

In your case, its not too clear to me where you would want your data, so I made some suggestion:

Assuming your sheet **WSB** contains the ID of the row from sheet **WSA** you want, in a sheet **WSC** you could write the following:

```
=INDEX(WSA!A1:C2,WSB!A1,2)
```

This would effectively return you the second column value (in your case **Doe**) in the range of your data:

- `WSA!A1:C2` : The range your are looking in
- `WSB!A1` : The id of the row in the above range you want to lookup (dynamically from the value in sheet WSB)
- **2** : The column of the range you want as a return value of the row requested

If you'd want a concatenation, I would suggest:

- Adding a concatenated column at the end of your WSA data
- Extending the range to D2
- Replacing the 2 in the above function by 4 (assuming your concatenated string is in column 4 on sheet WSA)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! Actually, I want to have this behavior in WSB. So I enter number 2 in WSB:A1, and instead seeing 2, I actually see data from WSA row 2. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can actually type one thing and then show another in the same cell you typed in. What I would do in that case is make a column that contains the row id and next to it one that will show the values. Then, when everything is finished, just hide the column with the IDs.

Comment: After some Googling I realized that I'm trying to enter the INDEX function in Format Cells -> Number -> Custom -> Type. Is that possible? I agree that I could add another column with the ID and then hide it, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: I don't think you can enter a function in a custom format type field. Even if you could that, i wouldn't know how you would reference the ID-value in the field. I get the idea behind it, but I don't think Excel is that clever :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll use a separate ID column in that case :)